# What are KuduHandles in the Azure Process Explorer?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are using PowerShell to query the process endpoint to get information that you can see if you use the `KUDU Process Explorer`.

We now see these processes getting created when using `Invoke-RestMethod`.

1. Do these processes impact the web app?
2. Can we close these Processes from Powershell programmatically?

`id          : 00001
name        : KuduHandles
href        : https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/processes/00001
user_name   : IIS APPPOOL\{sitename}
Environment : xyz
WebJobName  : abc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KuduHandles is a tool used by Kudu to list open file handles inside a process using only user mode calls. You can find sources on https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduHandles.

It should only be running briefly while Kudu gets the list of handles. If you're curious, you can run it manually from Kudu Console, e.g. (pass it the ID of some running process):

```
D:\home>kuduhandles 11916
D:\Windows
D:\home
D:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\cmd.exe.mui
D:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui
```